# HTML to PDF itextSharp - handling multiple fonts and unicode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fonts, itext, html-to-pdf

Folks, we are trying to convert HTML to PDF via itextSharp (v5.x) in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. Please note that the html has Chinese and English characters (as an example) with numeric formatting according by culture.

While we did register following fonts - Arial, Microsoft Yahei and Yu Gothic (these are the fonts that the browser is essentially using to display our content), the PDF is somehow only taking Yahei and thus few characters such as   are being devoured.

We have ensured that the html contains font family as the above three fonts, we have also loaded tagstyle with these fonts as font family with encoding set to Identity-H.

Is this happening because itext does not allow rendering with multiple fonts in html? (HTML is being extracted from a template with data filled via backend code.

EDIT:
Here is the code snippet portion that we need help with:
(We need to register multiple fonts as the html uses them. However only last registered font is applied)

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(html);
Document pdfDoc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);  
//Register a single font 
//FontFactory.Register(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "Fonts") + "\\arial-unicode-ms.ttf", "Arial Unicode MS");
// create a style sheet and set the encoding to Identity-H        
StyleSheet style = new StyleSheet();               
//Set the default body font to our registered font's internal name                
style.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Arial Unicode MS");           
//Set the default encoding to support Unicode characters               
style.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);     
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc, null, style);
```

Comment: Rotativa does a good job of this. https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa

Comment: Please post the pivotal part of your code, because your question is not clear now.

Comment: @Steve, I checked it. looks good. However iText5 is embedded in many of our applications. So replacing it is a bit of a challenge :(

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, i have posted the code snippet. We need help in registering multiple fonts (which we have mentioned as part of html).